# sql select min, return value from different column in same row with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want the OrderType for the min(Date) for each Name. 
So, I want this:

```
Name    Date        OrderType
Alex    1/1/2014    Direct
Alex    9/15/2014   Distributor
Cindy   6/4/2014    Distributor
John    5/8/2014    Direct
John    2/14/2014   Distributor
```

to return this:

```
Name    Date        OrderType
Alex    1/1/2014    Direct
Cindy   6/4/2014    Distributor
John    2/14/2014   Distributor
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit @JChao!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can get row number based on the date  for each `[Name]` and pick the least date record.

```
SELECT [T].* 
FROM (  
    SELECT [Name]
         , [DATE]
         , [OrderType]
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Date]) AS [seq]
    FROM [TableA]
) AS [T]
WHERE [T].[seq] = 1
```

Comment: Mind blown. Perfect solution! THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

I think you need select the min date per person then join back to the original table to get the type for that row.

Assuming your table is called tab and each person only had one order per date (otherwise the question is impossible) then something like:

```
Select t.name, t.date, t.ordertype
From tab t,
     ( select min (i.date) date, i.name from tab i group by i.name) t2
Where t.date = t2.date
  And t.name = t2.name
```

Sorry I work mainly with mysql and Oracle not tsql so it is generic sql syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
( Name VARCHAR(50), orderdate DATE, OrderType VARCHAR(50) )
INSERT #tmp ( Name, orderdate, OrderType )
VALUES  ( 'Alex', '01/01/2014','Direct')
INSERT #tmp
VALUES  ( 'Alex', '9/15/2014','Distributor')
INSERT #tmp
VALUES  ( 'Cindy', '6/4/2014','Distributor')
INSERT #tmp
VALUES  ( 'John', '5/8/2014','Direct')
INSERT #tmp
VALUES  ( 'John', '2/14/2014','Distributor')


; WITH CTE_RESULT AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY ORDERDATE ASC) ROW_NO , Name, orderdate, OrderType
    FROM #tmp
)

SELECT  * FROM CTE_RESULT T WHERE T.ROW_NO=1
```

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
select 
a.name, 
MIN(a.date)as date, 


from dbname a i
inner join (select name, min(date), ordertype from dbname) b on b.name=a.name and a.date=b.date

group by a.name, b.ordertype
```

Comment: I didn't down vote this but your query would return all 5 rows as it is grouped on name and ordertype.